# Como compartilhar menu entre aplicações ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Como compartilhar menu entre aplicações? Temos várias aplicações e todas tem o mesmo menu, exemplo:

Home | Beneficiário | Credenciado

Quando surge novo item precisamos fazer replicação em todas aplicações. Tentamos usar jquery.

```
<div id='idteste'></div> 
$('#idteste').load(/controle/action/)
```

Quando fazemos isso temos o problema do CORS que teria que habilitar no MVC Core, mesmo habilitando o CORS ele recebe css e js do outro site mudando o site atual, sendo segundo problema.

Tem também a opção de usarmos <  iframe > mas acho que deve ter alguma outra forma de resolver esse problema de compartilhar somente menu entre aplicações.

Comment: Se o problema são novos itens no menu, por que você não armazena esses itens/menu no banco e carrega eles quando o usuário acessar o sistema?

Comment: O problema disso é tbm questão de estilo por exemplo se precisar mudar cor ou fonte teria que fazer isso em todos os outros concorda ?

Comment: Entendi, eu faria os itens e o css/js do menu ser carregado e adicionado a página dinamicamente, buscando esses dados em uma API, aí você poderia ter um padrão e personalizações, mas por que habilitando o CORS e buscando o menu em outra aplicação ele alterou o site atual?

Comment: Sim ele altera fazendo com ajax, com API não sei como seria ou faria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver o problema carregando os itens e o css/js do menu dinamicamente:

Armazena no banco os itens do menu e no login do usuário você busca eles e armazena em session ou algo assim para não precisar buscar toda vez que o usuário navegar na aplicação.

Os arquivos css/js do menu devem conter apenas o conteúdo referente ao menu e ai você escolhe um projeto para hospedar eles, digamos o original, e depois você chama o endereço dessa aplicação original nas outras aplicações para carregar o arquivo como por exemplo as vezes usamos o jquery da cdn

Exemplo do jquery sendo buscado externamente:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Nos outros projetos você chama o css/js com o endereço do original no src e href

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="enderecoDoCssDoMenuDoSiteOriginal" />
<script src="enderecoDoJSDoMenuDoSiteOriginal"></script>
```

Lembrando que você tem que configurar o seu projeto para permitir o acesso a apenas esses dois arquivos ou hospedar eles em um local que permita isso, como o seu servidor e ai todos os projetos buscam o arquivo la, e você altera esses arquivos separadamente do projeto

Comment: Obrigado funcionou...